# Connecting to a postgres database dump from Heroku with R

Tags: r, postgresql, heroku

I have downloaded a backup of a postgres database from my Heroku server. The file that was downloaded has no extension -- it appears to be a blank text file.

I'm trying to load the database into R to run various queries on it. In the past, with a mySQL database, I'm able to connect with it via RSQLite like so:

```
install.packages("RSQLite")
library(RSQLite)
sql_df <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "database.db")
```

However, when I try to do this with the postgres dump like so,

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), 'postgres_dump')
```

I get an error:

```
Error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

All of the tutorials I find online assume I'm connecting to a database that is hosted online, rather than offline. How would I connect to a heroku local database dump via R?

Update: I just installed postgres via

`brew install postgresql`

I also installed postgresql-13.3 directly from [this website](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/)

I then re-ran the DBI::dbConnect line from above, and am now getting the following error:

`Error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

But I don't understand why there's a password or a username? I assumed accessing this database would be as easy as it is with a MySQL database, but clearly there's something I'm not understanding.

Comment: The error is telling where to look, namely the driver can't connect to Postgres on a socket at 5432. This is either because the Postgres server is not running? Or it is running and not listening on port 5432? Or it is up and listening on port 5432, but there is a library issue that is causing it to look at the wrong location for the socket. What OS and version are you running? How was Postgres installed? Add information as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks so much for helping! I just installed Postgres (didn't realize it was something that needed to be installed), and am getting a new error. Any thoughts? I'm running Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Installing two versions will not make things easier. I would uninstall one and concentrate on getting connected to the other one. Also if you stick with second install add to your question exactly which package you installed. Once that is done then we get to the connection errors.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your patience. I did `brew uninstall postgresql`, so I'm keeping the one manually downloaded which is postgres 13.3

Comment: But exactly which package did you download for 13.3?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by packages. I just clicked through the installer, which seems to have installed the PostgreSQL Server, pgAdmin 4, Stack Builder, and Command Line Tools. With these additional details: `Database Port: 5432`
`Database Superuser: postgres`, `Operating System Account: postgres`
`Database Service: postgresql-13`

Comment: On that page there are four other packages then the EDB one you installed, which is why I asked. Now you should be able to connect as user 'postgres' using the password you where asked to create as part of the install process.

Comment: Hmm, I'm now doing this in R: `con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), "database_dump_9_2_2021", user = "postgres", password = "mypassword")` and I'm getting the error `Error: FATAL: database "database_dump_9_2_2021" does not exist` even though I can see it exists in the main directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235566/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-parseltongue).